# Function Send from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've tried to pass the "hide" value for delete a record. But the JS function send the data but the mysql code don't work.
With the "insert to" it works, for this it's strange that the same code don't work.

```
This is my code.

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function invia()
     {
        var hides = document.getElementById('hide').value;

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "note_db_php/delete_db_note.php",
              data: {"hide": hides},
              success: function(data){
                console.log("Dati inviati");
              },

              error: function(data) {
                console.log("Dati non inviati");
              }
          });
      };

    </script>
```

and this is the delete page;

```
    <?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $hide = $_POST["hide"];



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id='$hide'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The console.log it work, and print "Dati inviati". So really, I don't understand. I have not error's message. But still don't work.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?  Are there any JavaScript errors on the browser's development console?  In the development tools, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Your code is wide open to SQL injection, so what is the actual exact runtime query being executed?

Comment: can you console.log hide value before sending AJAX request and check that value exist or you are passing empty value. Also, the hide value is a string or integer type?

Comment: What do you think happens, if I manipulate the request and send `1 or 1` as value for `hide`? This is an example for SQL injection!

Comment: I think the troublesome value for `hide` would be `1' or '1`, which then yields: `DELETE FROM note WHERE id='1' or '1'`. But the point @Wiimm was making is that you need to use prepared statements or you leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks. In this example, the "wrong" value entered either intentionally or not would result in all of your rows being deleted (assuming the rest of the code works correctly).

Comment: @Booboo: You and I are right: I'm before the edit of the question, and you after it.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code is not working -- you haven't described in any detail what error messages you are getting. But what *other* problem you have is that you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks and so you should be using a prepared statement. If this also corrects your problem (doubtful), that's a bonus:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM note WHERE id=?");
/* Bind our parameter: */
$stmt->bind_param('i', $hide); // assuming $hide is an integer value, else use 's' for string
$success = $stmt->execute(); // execute the statement
if (!$success) {
    error code here
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: The problem is this, I have not error's message, just this code dont delete record on DB. And this is strange because without JS it work!

Comment: @CarloPennetta: Then now is the time to do some debugging.  Relying on the `success` handler in your JavaScript *only* tells you that the response was a successful HTTP code.  Looking at your server-side code, there's no reason it wouldn't respond like that.  But you need to also examine what's in that response.  Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the complete AJAX response from the server.  What does it contain?  Add useful output in your server-side code (such as echoing the value of `$sql`) and observe that in your debugging tools.  What does it contain?  You need to debug.

Comment: Is the JavaScript code logging "Dati iviati" or "Diati non inviati" or neither? Do you know whether you are making it back up to your PHP code? The "echo" statements will be sent back to the AJAX request so you will not see them on your screen. You can try writing some output to a log file with `file_put_contents` instead of using `echo`. But you really should replace your code with a prepared statement. Read my comment to your original question concerning passing a value of `1' or '1` for `hide`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the sql query - $sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id=$hide";

Can you put the $hide in single quotes and try?

$sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id='$hide'"; // this will work

Comment: Why should that be neccessary?

Answer (score -1):

here your problem in sql syntax, and one line

> enter code here 
>   after else open on your code that causing error

updated query here , its working

```
// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id='$hide'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed and why? Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: nope, still the problem, I dont understand, the code it work, but with the function don't delete.
But delete page work.

Comment: can you give your page link so that we can check or complete code how you calling function , and what error you getting in debugging? untill you wont report debugg error how we will look over it and you just voting down to all answer as i seen , so

Answer (score -1):

The attribute `dataType` is missing and `type` should be `method`.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"note_db_php/delete_db_note.php",
  method:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{
    "hide": hides
  },
  success:function(data) {
    console.log("Dati inviati"); 
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log("Dati non inviati");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your query -

`$sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id='$hide'";`

With below one -

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM note WHERE id = ".$hide;
```

And on the ajax end please console your `data`. If it is giving error then please echo your query (echo $sql), and copy and run the query in PHPMyAdmin.